# makefile last target not getting executed

Tags: makefile

```
word.o: word.c word.h
        gcc -c word.c
line.h: word.h
        touch line.h
```

Above is the contents of the makefile. when I execute make. 
I see the file `word.o` is created. But the file `line.h` is not.
What could be the reason for this? As far as I know, the make doesn't 
execute those targets which don't have any dependencies.
But here the dependency list is not empty, Still, it didn't get executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly make builds targets that don't have dependencies.  If a target has no dependencies, then it is considered out of date if it doesn't exist.

The problem is that make doesn't build every single target in the makefile: that would be bad because many people include `clean` targets, `test` targets, and other targets that they only want to run sometimes not every time.

You can read the introduction in the GNU make manual, specifically [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html#How-Make-Works), to understand what's happening.

Comment: `The other rules are processed because their targets appear as prerequisites of the goal` - This line probably explains it. So what I understand is there are certain targets which are *goals* and by default the first target is the only one that is set as the goal and no other (skipping the ones that start with a .)

Comment: The critical info is the very first sentence: _By default, make starts with the first target_.  In your makefile the first target is `word.o`, so that target (and its prerequisites) are all that's built by default.

Comment: If `line.h` is not "built", then it means it's newer than the `word.h` file so make doesn't have to do anything to bring it up to date.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to touch `line.h` if it's older than `word.h`; it seems like a very strange situation.  But maybe you have a strange requirement :)

Comment: I took this example from somewhere just to understand the working of the makefile. line.h not there only. It will get created when after `touch line.h`  which is not happening. I think the built and time question will come in when line.h was an existing file. So here what I understand is that the concept of **goal** is coming into the picture

Comment: `line.h` is not touched because the first target, `word.o`, does not depend on it and, as I mention above, only the first target (and its prerequisites) are built by default.  If you run `make line.h` then it will get updated.  What most makefiles do is create a first target that depends on all the targets they normally want to build and which aren't depended on by some other target.  This target is often called `all`, but it can be whatever you want.  So if you add `all: word.o line.h` as the first thing in your makefile, both will be created.